# Is it possible to have an infinite paging with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I would like to have a viewpager in which I load a page every time the user swipe right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Check this blog post with the implementation:
http://thehayro.blogspot.com/2012/12/enable-infinite-paging-with-android.html